# How to set keyboard key pressed event only once after pressed but not continously

Tags: phaser-framework

I am using below code to move the player up, but the problem is as long as the button is pressed and held the player continues to move. How can I change this behaviour so that no matter how much time the button is pressed for the player moves only once?

```
if (cursor.up.isDown){
     player.body.velocity.y = -200;
     player.animations.stop('move');
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bool acting as a flip-flop switch should do the job:

```
var flipFlop;

function update() {
    if (cursor.up.isDown){
        if (!flipFlop) {
            player.body.velocity.y = -200;
            player.animations.stop('move');
            flipFlop = true;
        }
    }

    if (cursor.up.isUp) {
        flipFlop = false;
    }
}
```

Note that the flipFlop variable is declared outside the update loop, otherwise it will be recreated every frame.

Comment: thanx kamen, i had implemented a similar & much simpler flipflop & now everything is working fine!!

Answer (score 1):

Kamen Minkov answer does work, but if your idea is to make a jump the bool will not work, as soon you realese the button you can press it agan and go further up, even not touching any ground.

But you can use this function to verify if the body is touching down

```
function touchingDown(someone) {
var yAxis = p2.vec2.fromValues(0, 1);
var result = false;
for (var i = 0; i < game.physics.p2.world.narrowphase.contactEquations.length; i++) {
    var c = game.physics.p2.world.narrowphase.contactEquations[i];
    if (c.bodyA === someone.data || c.bodyB === someone.data)        {
        var d = p2.vec2.dot(c.normalA, yAxis); // Normal dot Y-axis
        if (c.bodyA === someone.data) d *= -1;
        if (d > 0.5) result = true;
    }
} return result;
}
```

and call sending the body

```
if ( (cursor.up.isDown) && (touchingDown(player.body)) ){
        player.body.velocity.y = -200;
        player.animations.stop('move');
}
```

OBS: function for P2 Physics, but for arcade the body already have a field that says if it is touching down.

Comment: I had used a simple flip flop in collide event callback & everything is working fine now thanks!!

Comment: The flipflop inside a collide event, thats clever.

Answer (score 0):

I know this an old post but i got stuck here too and used your example to come up with this nice and simple solution

```
this.speed = 100
this.player.setVelocity(0,0)
if (this.cursors.left.isDown){
  this.player.setVelocityX(-this.speed)
}else if(this.cursors.right.isDown){
  this.player.setVelocityX(this.speed)
}else{
  this.player.setVelocityX(0)
}if(this.cursors.up.isDown){
  this.player.setVelocityY(-this.speed)
}else if (this.cursors.down.isDown){
  this.player.setVelocityY(+this.speed)
}else{
  this.player.setVelocityY(0)
}
```

First we set the players velocity to 0 , 0 (both x and y).
We check for any changes on the x axis else reset that back to 0.
Check on the y axis for changes else reset that back to 0 also.

This i found allows the character to move in a more fluid motion. and also allows for both left and up etc to be pressed together.
if you need the character to move more square like then change velocity to .x or .y